# compile all the stored procedures in bulk

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried to compile all the stored procedures in SSMS in bulk. But only the first stored procedure is compiled and then for other procedures shows "*There is already an object...*" I kept all the procedures in one editor then tried compiling [F5] the procedures but getting the error. Please suggest how to compile all the procedures in bulk.

Here is the sample what I am trying to do :

```
USE [TESTDB]    
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_Codes]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_Codes]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_Codes]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 8:56:32 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_Codes]
    as

    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
            --- my stored procedure
        end
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;


    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_retailers]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_retailers]

    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_retailers]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 8:58:43 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_retailers]
    as

    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
            --- my stored procedure
        end
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;


    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_Buyers]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_Buyers]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_Buyers]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 10:17:53 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_Buyers]
    as
    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin   
            --- my stored procedure
        end 
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;


    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 10:23:39 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]

    as
    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
            --- my stored procedure 
        end 
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to parse? or trying to create/alter them?

Comment: trying to create procedure. drop if exists and create procedures in bulk.

Comment: Added answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `go` before each `IF` statement which checks the existance of stored procedure

Your script should be this

```
USE [TESTDB]    
IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_Codes]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_Codes]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_Codes]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 8:56:32 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_Codes]
    as

    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
            --- my stored procedure
        end
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;

GO
    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_retailers]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_retailers]

    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_retailers]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 8:58:43 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_retailers]
    as

    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
            --- my stored procedure
        end
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;

GO
    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_Buyers]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_Buyers]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_Buyers]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 10:17:53 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_Buyers]
    as
    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin   
            --- my stored procedure
        end 
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;

GO
    IF OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id('[dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]'), N'IsProcedure') = 1
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]
    GO
    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]    Script Date: 8/8/2015 10:23:39 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    create proc [dbo].[p_get_seller_groups]

    as
    begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        begin
            --- my stored procedure 
        end 
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    end;
```